# Private variable getting exposed/modified

Tags: java, private, public

I'm confused as to why my private variables are getting exposed and modified by other classes and it's making me frustrated that I can't figure out where my concept/understanding went wrong. Please help.

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    private String[] privateStringArr = new String[10];

    Test() { }

    public String[] getStringArr() {
        String[] cover = privateStringArr;
        return cover;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    static Test testClass = new Test();
    static String[] shouldBePrivate = testClass.getStringArr();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(testClass.getStringArr()[0]);
        shouldBePrivate[0] = "hello";
        System.out.println(shouldBePrivate[0]);
        System.out.println(testClass.getStringArr()[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
null
hello
hello
```

Why is modifying `shouldBePrivate` also modifying `privateStringArr` in `testClass`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's NOT private at all!

Comment: Private just means you can't access the variable directly using its name, like `testClass.privateStringArr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you return a link to the same object here

```
public String[] getStringArr() {
        String[] cover = privateStringArr; // <- no new object is created
        return cover;
    }
```

You can return a copy instead

```
public String[] getStringArr() {
        return privateStringArr.clone();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `public String[] getStringArr()` you are passing a non private reference to `StringArr`:

```
public String[] getStringArr() {
    String[] cover = privateStringArr;
    return cover;
}
```

So in your main you are able to modify it. You need to return a true copy of `privateStringArr`. You can use `clone()` or [`System.arrayscopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

After the following step:

```
static String[] shouldBePrivate = testClass.getStringArr();
```

All modifications on `shouldBePrivate` will affect the `privateStringArr` since they are the references to same array object. Both variables refer the same array. If you modify the array both variables will be affected.

In order to avoid it, `return Arrays.copyOf(privateStringArr , privateStringArr .length);` should be returned at `getStringArr()`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, almost everything (except primitive vales like `int` or `char`) is a *reference* or *pointer* - what's stored in the variable is not the value itself, but an address in memory where the actual data is.

```
cover = privateStringArr
shouldBePrivate = testClass.getStringArr()
```

These two assignments don't copy the actual data in Java - they merely copy the address in memory where the data is.

```
private String[] privateStringArr = new String[10]; // create an array of 10 Strings, and store the address in privateStringArr
String[] cover = privateStringArr;                  // copy address to cover
return cover;                                       // return the address stored in cover
String[] shouldBePrivate = testClass.getStringArr();// copy returned address to shouldBePrivate
shouldBePrivate[0] = "hello";                       // find the data at address read from shouldBePrivate and modify it's first element
testClass.getStringArr()[0]                         // find the data at address returned from getStringArr() and read the first element
```

Comment: I see, so if I use the `.clone()` method it will create a new memory address for my variable?

Comment: `clone()` will allocate new place in memory, copy the data from original and return this new address. However, be aware of two things: a) There's a distinction of [*shallow copy* vs *deep copy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy) you need to understand, and b) [the `clone()` method is broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) and should be mostly avoided. `clone()` itself does shallow copy, which in your simple case should suffice, but it might not be enough if your array item was a mutable type instead of `String`.